# Evolution equation and invertible operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I want to prove the existence and uniqueness of the following problem by the semi-group method 
$$
\eqalign{
  & {u_{tt}} + {u_{xxtt}} + {u_t} - {u_{xx}} = 0  \cr 
  & u(t,0) = u(t,l) = 0  \cr 
  & u(0) = {u_{0{\rm{   }}}}  ,u'(0) = {u_1} \cr} 
$$ 
I wrote it as a Cauchy problem :
 $$U' = AU$$ with : $U = ({v^1},{v^2})$ and  $A$ is defined as : $$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
   0 & I  \\[3pt]
   \Big(I + \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2}\Big)^{ - 1}\!\!\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2} &  - \Big(I + \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial  x^2}\Big)^{ - 1}
 \end{pmatrix} 
$$
My question is how can I treat the operator ${(I + {{{\partial ^2}} \over {\partial {x^2}}})^{ - 1}}$ ? 
Thank you

Comment: What about Fourier series?

Comment: @guacho: Not good on a bounded domain...

Comment: Is this post related to your issue? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32932/how-can-one-relate-inverse-of-a-differential-operator-to-an-integral-operator